# How to use awscli inside ruby script?

Tags: ruby, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, aws-cli

I have a awscli command to upload content to s3 bucket. I need to run this command on a ruby script. The command works when executed in terminal. I tried using several methods like `backticks` and `Kernel#system`.

```
value = `aws s3 cp #{published_files} s3://example_bucket/#{meeting_id} --recursive --region us-west-2`
```

But none of them seem to execute the task. Can anyone suggest any way? It would be of great help

Comment: Have you tried AWS Ruby client https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sdkforruby/api/Aws/S3/Client.html ? Could you please specify what do you have stderr/stdout while executing from the Ruby script? Do you execute the script in the same environment where you run the awscli command?

Comment: @Yann This script is run as a result of finishing an online classroom where the script would receive the path to the recording of the classroom. I need to upload the recording to the bucket. I executed the command in the same server.

Comment: @Yann I do not need the response. I just need this cli command to run.

Comment: The response may content the actual error that happens while trying to execute the command. `Kernel#system` should work. Try these debug steps: execute the command in `irb`, try simple aws commands without parameters like `aws s3api list-buckets`, print the aws command with inserted parameters and verify they are correct.

Answer (score 1):

Use the sdk instead as it has native support for using s3 https://github.com/aws/aws-sdk-ruby

The API docs are listed here https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sdk-for-ruby/v3/api/Aws/S3.html

Comment: I need to upload a folder which is quite hard to achieve through the sdk. This cli command should work if I'm able to execute it from the ruby script.

Comment: then have the ruby script call a bash script with your command in the script

Comment: any idea on how to call a bash script from ruby script?

Comment: https://www.rubyguides.com/2018/12/ruby-system/
system(bash /path/to/your/script)